# How to get total rows in Drupal 8 view with pagination?

Tags: drupal, view

In Drupal 8, I use a view with pagination. There are 10 items per page.

In hook_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {..} I want to get the number of items to use in another function. However, $result = 10 and $total_rows = 10 due to the pager setting. The actual item number is between 500 and 2000.
As a workaround I tried a temporary view.

```
$view2 = Views::getView('my_view');
$view2->setDisplay('page_1');
$view2->setItemsPerPage(15000);
$view2->execute();
```

This works. view2->total_rows returns the desired value. But I don't want to use a fixed value in setItemsPerPage. 0 or null (for unlimited items per page) returns no result for total_rows.

What can I do to get the correct number of views-items?

Answer (score 1):

In your hook_views_pre_render function, instead of calling view->SetDisplay and view->setItemsPerPage, you can execute the view (even with pager settings) and get the total rows/results:

```
  $view = Views::getView('my_view');
  $view->execute('page_1');
  $rows = $view->total_rows;
```

$rows will provide the total count that you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you @Anson W Han. Unfortunately $rows = 10. It seems as if the view does not ignore pager settings.

Comment: can you provide the code for your entire hook?  I tested with various pager settings and always get the expected result.  Also, can you confirm in your pager settings, you have a pager type set, and not "display a specified number of items"?

Answer (score 1):

And get_total_rows needs to be set to true for total_rows to operate.

```
$view = Views::getView('my_view');
$view->get_total_rows = TRUE;
$view->execute('page_1');
$rows = $view->total_rows;
```